# Why is there a difference in speed when using different boolean structures in Android (Eclipse)?

Tags: android, bitmap, boolean, lag

By playing around with code, I have found that these two blocks of code seem to have different speeds. Notice how the if statements are different. Both compile **without** a problem on my emulator, but the second block of code lags slightly. Does anyone know why? (I seldom use the structure in the second block)

```
    Bitmap temp;//td.getPlayClicked(), getPlayUnclicked(),etc. returns a different Bitmap
    Canvas canvas;//this runs fine, it is instantiated in my thread class, I'm just showing what type each object is.

    for(int alg=0;alg<td.getBitmaps();alg++){
       if(temp.equals(td.getPlayClicked())||temp.equals(td.getPlayUnclicked())){
           canvas.drawBitmap(drawing.get(alg),this.getWidth()/2-td.getPlayClicked().getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()*2/3, null);
           }
       }
```

versus:

```
   for(int alg=0;alg<td.getBitmaps();alg++){
       if(drawing.get(alg).equals(td.getClicked()?td.getPlayClicked():td.getPlayUnclicked())){
           canvas.drawBitmap(drawing.get(alg),this.getWidth()/2-td.getPlayClicked().getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()*2/3, null);
           }
    }
```

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely what is going on, rather than guessing.

Comment: `the second block of code lags slightly` - how do you know?

Comment: Just a guess, the first code block contains a boolean or statement which is interpreted from left to right. If the first term of that statement already evaluates to true then the if statement condition is true and the rest won't be evaluated. In your second block you enforce that quite a few method calls are always executed: get -> equals -> getClicked and then either getPlayClicked or getPlayUnclicked get executed. Especially when it comes to image processing on Android (using Java) method calls have an impact.